# How to convert this cURL command to XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, curl, xmlhttprequest, multipart

I'm trying to send a request with multipart/mixed content type in JS. This is the cURL command that I'm using and it works:

```
curl -k -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed" -H "Timestamp: 2017-
04-20'T'13:15:05" -H "AuthToken: A834F35B21E7BE50067B3E352BED" -F 
"config=@request.json;type=application/json" -F "logo=@random2.gif" 
https://pmdev.****.com:8443/core/admin/hospital/26/department/63
```

Here is the code I'm trying to use in JS, but it doesn't work:

```
let blob = new Blob([ JSON.stringify(config) ], {type:
'application/json'})

var formData = new FormData()
formData.append('config', blob)
formData.append('logo', logo)

var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open(method, url)
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/mixed')
request.setRequestHeader('AuthToken', authToken)
request.setRequestHeader('Timestamp', getTimestamp())
request.send(formData)
```

How can I fix this code?

Comment: press f12 and check network calls. what does its showing?

Comment: I suggest you use [axios package](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#config-defaults).

Comment: Is this a cross origin request? Use browser dev tools to provide troubleshooting details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i managed to solve this by using axios,
this is the code I have used

```
  let formData = new FormData()
  let blob = new Blob([ JSON.stringify(config) ], {type: 'application/json'})
  formData.append('config', blob)
  formData.append('logo', logo)

  axios.post(url, formData, {
    headers: {
      'AuthToken' : authToken,
      'Timestamp' : getTimestamp(),
      'Content-type': 'multipart/mixed'
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(config)], {type: 'application/json'});
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('config',blob);
formData.append('logo',logo);
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST',url);
request.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
request.send(formData);
```

//i think you reference the contents of the form data incorrectly, i deleted //reference to them. you should use 'POST' as your method because itll set up //your formData automatically (pretty sure on that, it seems like a far out //assertion though). also, i changed all the types to be json.

//this page has all the formData methods on it: that way you can get at the //info attached to your POST
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: no all the references are ok , my method is 'POST' too